# CLIPS Is there a function similar to contains in C#?

Tags: string-matching, clips

Hi i m writing a program that will simulate the propositional laws. I would like to ensure that certain characters are not contained within my variables. Is there a easy function to do this.

I currently have it working if my variable is only a single character but would like to make it work with a multi-slot variable.

```
(deftemplate sentence (multislot sent))

(defrule read-from-user
 =>
(bind ?response "")
(printout t "Please enter a sentence: Use ~ for not and => for implies, or(v) and and(^) please. For predicates use { and } Example exists{richard}" crlf)
(bind ?response (explode$ (readline)))
 (bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "(" (sym-cat "(")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response ")" (sym-cat ")")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "~" (sym-cat "~")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "v" (sym-cat "v")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "=>" (sym-cat "=>")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "^" (sym-cat "^")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "[" (sym-cat "[")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "]" (sym-cat "]")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "{" (sym-cat "{")))
(bind ?response (replace-member$ ?response "}" (sym-cat "}")))

(assert (sentence (sent ?response))))


(defrule negative
(sentence (sent $?before "~" "(" "~" ?symbol ")" $?after))
(test (neq ?symbol "~" "(" ")" "=" "^" "v"))
=>
(assert (sentence (sent $?before $?symbol $?after))))
```

This piece of code works for single characters but i know what to make the 
?Symbol into $?symbol and still check that none of the character (,),~,= etc are in ?$symbol.

So if there is any similar function to compare in C# that i can use her? thx guys

Answer (score 0):

Use the str-index function to determine if a sequence of characters is contained within a string:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 4/4/19)
CLIPS> (str-index "^" "abc")
FALSE
CLIPS> (str-index "^" "ab^c")
3
CLIPS>
```

Comment: I just have one ore question how woul i write a function to test for all those strings i mentioned above? Otherwise i will have to check for all these strings at all my rules and that would suck so could i possibly make a function to do so and just call that function?

Comment: (deffunction my-test (?symbol) (not (or (str-index "^" ?symbol) (str-index "v" ?symbol))))

Comment: This is perfect but i cannot pass a $?variable to this function. It says that is expecting a string or synbol. What cionversion must i do to a $? variable to be able to pass it to a deffunction? Thank you very much for your help the last few days gary :)